# Instance variable becomes undefined - CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
class Game

  foo: null

  play: ->

    @foo = 2
    @animate()

  animate: ->

    requestAnimationFrame( @animate, 1000 )
    console.log('foo = ', @foo)


$ ->
  game = null

  init = ->

    game = new Game()
    game.play()

  init()
```

The log in the animate method in Game produces:

foo = 2

foo = undefined

So foo is 2 on the first call to animate and then undefined thereafter. Could someone please explain why and how I can fix this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` doesn't take a number as the second argument; instead, it calls the given function ASAP (typically faster than `setTimeout(func, 0)` does) provided that the browser tab is in the foreground. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call `setInterval`, context is lost and the second time `@` is `window`.  You need fat-arrow methods to retain the appropriate `this`:

```
animate: =>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This has worked but has caused very strange behaviour with requestAnimationFrame. I am calling requestAnimationFrame as should be done but with the fat arrow it is kind of repeating the call over the other call to requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: @user881920 This repetition is the correct behavior. You should accept Aaron's answer. If you're having an issue with `requestAnimationFrame`, you should ask a separate question about it.

Answer (score 5):

You can define `animate` as follows:

```
animate: ->
  callback = (=> @animate())
  requestAnimationFrame(callback, 1000 )
  console.log('foo = ', @foo)
```

The technique here is to get a bound method. `@animate` by itself is *unbound*, but `(=> @animate())` is the bound version of it.

You can get a similar results if you're using UnderscoreJS as follows:

```
animate: ->
  callback = _.bind(@animate, @)
  requestAnimationFrame(callback, 1000 )
  console.log('foo = ', @foo)
```

And if you are using a later version of JavaScript, you may be able to do as follows:

```
animate: ->
  callback = @animate.bind(@)
  requestAnimationFrame(callback, 1000 )
  console.log('foo = ', @foo)
```